# Github for Windows not adding new files

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am using Github for Windows to manage several Git repos. For one of a newly cloned repo, it seems that newly created files appear in the 'X files too be committed' list, but after clicking on the `Commit` button, a new commit is created but the newly created files are still uncommitted!

[image]

I can continue to commit the same files over and over again, creating new commits each time, but the newly created files are simply not committed unless I go to the command prompt and manually do `git add .`

Is there a setting in Github for Windows that I have missed?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I'm in the same boat.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz Nope :( This sucks

Comment: I've sent GitHub an email about this and linked this SO question in my description of the bug.

Comment: I did the same some time ago and that's part of the answer I got: "It's a known issue that will be fixed shortly (we just need to ship GitHub for Windows with the updates LibGit2Sharp library). You can see the related issue here: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/1766". So they know about it and how to fix it, but haven't done so yet.

Comment: Till today (09-Aug-2016), this issue page is 404 and the problem persists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I don't think you are missing anything. I just tested this and this is not the default behaviour. Normally after you commit, the files should be flagged as unsynced. When you click `Sync` button the committed changes should be pushed to the `upstream`.

This is most probably a bug.

**Before commit:**

[image: Before commit]

**After commit :**

[image: After commit]

Comment: Hope the bug gets fixed soon!

Comment: Not fixed yet :/ I'll see if there is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Best I can tell, GitHub for Windows doesn't properly recognize file differences that only vary by line endings (at least in the scenarios I've found). I had multiple javascript files that consisted of something like:

```
- (function(){
-   function foo(){
-     return 'bar';
-   }
- )();
+ (function(){
+   function foo(){
+     return 'bar';
+   }
+ )();
```

Which, at first glance didn't make sense. Then, after I looked in to it, the variance was the file went from a `\r\n` line ending to `\n` (or the inverse). FWIW, I have the following setup in `.gitattributes`:

```
* text=auto
```

However, I was able to resolve it by using the shell. First, a `git status` showed me I did, indeed, have several files with modifications (and git even told me they varied by line endings):

```
.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in Project/Path/file.js
```

then, i used `git commit -a` to add those files, and finally `git push` to send them up to the repository. I now (even according to GitHub for Windows) have a syncd branch.